# Response.ContentType, BufferOutput vs <@ Page

Tags: vb.net, contenttype

In VS 2010, is

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Buffer="true" ContentType="image/jpeg" %>
```

equivalent to

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%
    Response.BufferOutput = True
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
%>
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the same. I used Resharper's "Navigate to Decompile Sources" for Page.Buffer property and it sets the Response properties.